# Why is an index not used on a LIKE query with wildcards?

Tags: mysql, explain

Although the Title column was added as index by using the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE Recipe ADD INDEX Title_idx (Title)
```

MySQL doesn't use that index for this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Recipe
WHERE Title LIKE '%cake%';
```

I used the `EXPLAIN` keyword and the key field is `NULL`.

How to solve it? I have to improve that query.

Comment: MySQL cannot use an index when you have a `%` wildcard at the start of the string. If your query was `LIKE 'cake%'`, the index would be used.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: If you know the answer please write it as one. Comments are for requesting clarification.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm searching for the duplicate I know exists. Hold tight...

Comment: I understood, but since I can't use indexes how I can improve my search query?

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Since MySQL 5.6 introduced Full Text Indexes for InnoDB, I will use it. Just a question @MichaelBerkowski: Have I to delete my question since it's duplicated?

Comment: @Fabio No, it's fine to leave it, because it will turn up in searches to point to more complete answers. (especially if I edit the title a little)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a full-text index to match partially. Consider a normal index like a phone book: It's great for finding people by last name then first name, say "Smith, John", but useless for finding people with "ith" in their name, you'll have to go through entry by entry manually matching.

Any query that says `LIKE '%x%'` will automatically be a table scan. This will not scale for non-trivial sized tables.

Comment: How I can use a full-text index?

Comment: Like anything, step one is [reading the documentation on full-text indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html).

Answer (score 7):

Because an index start from the beginning of a string. Since you look for a substring at ANY position in the title, the index can't be used.

This could make use of an index

```
WHERE Title LIKE 'cake%';
```

but this not

```
WHERE Title LIKE '%cake%';
```